# multithreading with the trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

I have written a Trigger which is transferring a record from a table members_new to `members_old`. The Function of trigger is to insert a record into `members_old`  on **after insert** in `members_new`. So suppose a record is getting inserted into a `members_new` like

```
nMmbID   nMmbName  nMmbAdd 

1        Abhi     Bangalore
```

This record will get inserted into `members_old` with the same data structure of the table

My trigger is like :

```
create trigger add_new_record 
after 
insert on members_new
for each row 
INSERT INTO `test`.`members_old`
(
`nMmbID`, 
`nMmbName`,
`nMmbAdd`
)
(
SELECT
`members_new`.`nMmbID`, 
`members_new`.`nMmbName`,
`members_new`.`nMmbAdd`
FROM `test`.`members_new`
where nMmbID = (select max(nMmbID) from `test`.`members_new` // written to read   the last record from the members_new and stop duplication on the members_old , also this will reduce the chances of any error . ) 
)
```

This  trigger is working for now , but my confusion is that what will happen if a multiple insertion is happening   at one instance of time.

Will it reduce the performance?

Will I face deadlock condition ever in any case as my `members_old` have FKs?

If any better solution for this situation is there, please give limelight on that

Comment: I would guess that this is for `mysql`, but you really ought to add a specific tag when asking `sql` questions - different database engines have different facilities, performance, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html):

> You can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and NEW. OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.

```
create trigger add_new_record 
after 
insert on members_new
for each row 
INSERT INTO `test`.`members_old`
SET
`nMmbID` = NEW.nMmbID,
`nMmbName` = NEW.nMmbName,
`nMmbAdd` = NEW.nMmbAdd;
```

And you will have no problem with deadlocks or whatever. Also it should be much faster, because you don't have to read the max value before (which is also unsecure and might lead to compromised data). Read about isolation levels and transactions if you're interested why...